# Highcharts "Top 5 users" bar

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com/) bar-chart with the top 5 active users, in groups.
I need to be able to name the series different.
Like this:

```
        ------- John ------ 6
Users:  ---- Peter ---- 3
        --- Phil --- 1

        ------- Nathan ------ 8
Admins: ---- Henry ---- 4
        --- Ann --- 2
```

Is this even possible?
If yes, can someone send me in the right direction on how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show some code that you tried....

Comment: None.. I've looked around and not found the "good answer" yet.
Howover, this looks a bit like it:
http://jsfiddle.net/aCz2s/12/
But, I need different names on the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is a grouped axis labeling set up.

This is not supported directly, but there are a variety of workarounds, and there is a feature request for this functionality:

http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2230615-grouped-x-axis

You can add your votes and comments, and you can get some ways to solve your problem from the comments thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use renderer to add custom text on the bars.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text()